# Set different number of posts on Wordpress homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I created a Wordpress blog and set the default number of posts per page to 6. 
Now, I want to display only 4 posts on my homepage. So i created the following page template but I cannot find a way to limit the number of posts to 4. 
Any ideas?

```
    <?php /* Template Name: HP Blog */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main" class="main">
<div class="container">
<section id="content" class="content">
<?php do_action('cpotheme_before_content'); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<div class="page-content">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php $query = new WP_Query("post_type=post&paged=".cpotheme_current_page()."&posts_per_page=".get_option('posts_per_page')); ?>
<?php if($query->posts): ?>
<?php cpotheme_grid($query->posts, 'element', 'blog', cpotheme_get_option('blog_columns'), array('class' => 'column-narrow')); ?>
<div class="homepageposts"><a style="width:80%;" class="post-readmore button" href="/συμβουλές/">Δείτε όλα τα άρθρα</a></div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php do_action('cpotheme_after_content'); ?>
</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace this code

```
query = new WP_Query("post_type=post&paged=".cpotheme_current_page()."&posts_per_page=".get_option('posts_per_page'));
```

to

```
query = new WP_Query("post_type=post&paged=".cpotheme_current_page()."&posts_per_page="4");
```

Comment: Thanks Umar! I had to remove the " before the number 4 to work. This is the final code: query = new WP_Query("post_type=post&paged=".cpotheme_current_page()."&posts_per_page=4");

Comment: Just mark this as answerd to your query, so that it is helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution and simple solution can be setting that through backend/admin panel.

> Go to **Dashboard > Settings > Reading** and then set *Blog pages show at most* to
>   4.

Hope this helps!